# Como eu declaro uma operação ternária para que ela mostre em uma página HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
    function calcular() {
        var ns1 = window.document.getElementById('nt1')
        var n1 = Number(ns1.value)

        var ns2 = window.document.getElementById('nt2')
        var n2 = Number(ns2.value)

        var ns3 = window.document.getElementById('nt3')
        var n3 = Number(ns3.value)

        var ns4 = window.document.getElementById('nt4')
        var n4 = Number(ns4.value)

        var res = window.document.getElementById('res')

        var s = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4) / 4

        s >= 6 ? 'Aprovado':'Reprovado'

        res.innerHTML = `Resultado: ${s} `

    }
```

O valor de s era para mostrar Aprovado ou reprovado, mas ao invés disso só retorna o valor da média.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Atribua o resultado da expressão a uma variável, e use essa variável na saída:

```
var resultado = s >= 6 ? 'Aprovado' : 'Reprovado';
res.innerHTML = `Resultado: ${resultado}`;
```

Ou, como sugeriu o Maniero, faça a expressão ternária diretamente na *template string*:

```
res.innerHTML = `Resultado: ${s >= 6 ? 'Aprovado' : 'Reprovado'}`;
```

Qual usar vai depender da situação e de estilo, não existe regra.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Resolveu o meu problema.

Answer (score 3):

Você acredita demais em variáveis e curiosamente nesse caso a falta de uma foi o problema. Você fez a expressão e não guardou em lugar algum o resultado dela.

Em seguida tentou usar o valor da média e não o que queria imprimir que é o texto da aprovação ou reprovação.

Um dos problemas que causou isso foi o nome ruim da variável, não parece mas se tivesse chamado ela de `media` seria mais difícil usá-la no lugar do resultado esperado. Seria mais óbvio que está imprimindo algo errado

Dá para resolver bem esse problema com apenas uma variável (dá sem nenhuma, mas aí começa ficar ilegível, então evitarei).

```js
function calcular() {
    var media = (Number(window.document.getElementById('nt1').value) +
    Number(window.document.getElementById('nt2').value) +
    Number(window.document.getElementById('nt3').value) +
    Number(window.document.getElementById('nt4').value)) / 4;
    window.document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = `Resultado: ${media >= 6 ? 'Aprovado' : 'Reprovado'}`;
}
calcular();
```

```html
<input id="nt1" value="1">
<input id="nt2" value="2">
<input id="nt3" value="3">
<input id="nt4" value="4">
<div id="res">
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/AverageGrade.js).

Não tem nada erado criar outras variáveis, mas acho desnecessário, variável óbvia demais pra mim é ruído, a não ser que ela seja um resultado obrigatoriamente intermediário ou é usada mais de uma vez.

Comment: Eu não pensei em usar dessa maneira. Como eu estou aprendendo ainda o básico, estou muito preso ainda às variáveis.